# How padding works on SHA-3?

Tags: hash, padding, sha-3

I'm studying SHA-3 and I dont understand quite a bit how the padding 10*1 works. Can someone explain me step by step how is it work? Also I know that on SHA3-512 r is 576. On the sponge construction what you need to XOR the first padded message P0 with the r vector. What is the r vector in any situation?
(Please be nice with me Im just studying crypto for the first time also Im not an english native speaker)

Comment: I dont think there is such thing as an r vector, you XOR the padded message into the state r bits at a time

Comment: This may answer your question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33624/sha-3-padding-clarifications?rq=1

Comment: So what is r? Is it a predefined number?

Comment: How can you xor 576 with the padded number ?

Comment: yes, r is the rate, which is a defined constant. You XOR r bits of message into the 1600 bit state